# How to chedule a (long term) cron-task on a desktop?

Tags: cron

Every `crontab` command require as mandatory the minute, hour and day fields. Now supposing I just want that a certain script or command should be executed once every 3 months on my desktop. AFAIK crontab *command* and *file* was born to run on servers which ones are up and running 24/24h while I'm not sure that my desktop in 3 months by now will be up and running in a certain minute/hour/day.

Comment: Are you looking for `anacron`? It's basically the same as `cron` but also runs tasks which it 'missed'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a systemd timer with option `Persistent=true`:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#Realtime_timer